# Responsive data table not working in safari

Tags: css, safari

I trying to get a simple responsive table on safari to work.

I'm trying to set all table elements to `display:block` on small screens so they will be stacked on top of each other.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px)  {

    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }

    td:empty {
      display: none;
    }

}
```

The technic is explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/).

I'm trying to get [this simple jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mumuge/edit?html,css,output) to work and this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the the same issue today, my problem was I didn't have the doctype annotation in the html header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
etc...
```

This fixes your jsbin sample too...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Semantic-UI and have been struggling with this same problem in Safari.

Adding  `<!DOCTYPE html>` fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it looks like [this exact same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37898979/660921) was already provided half a year ago?